# Extract text from PDF into JSON or XML or whatever?

Tags: json, xml, pdf

I am trying to extract data [price, information, and number] from PDF (I have like more than 10 000 PDF so the free trial of the website won't work).
Here is one example of PDF I get :

[image]

I tried it in Python (beginner on this kind of task and on Python also) with several packages like PyPDF2, pdfx and so on, but I only get the Text like this

with PyPDF2 :

[image]

So It's possible to extract the price, the number, and information but I have different format of pdf so it is not possible to just with the text and some algorithms extract the information.

What I want to do, and it is possible because a lot of websites are doing it and make people pay for it. I want to read it in a vertical way and convert the data extracted in XML/JSON or simply a dataset.

I want to read the document per columns and not by line

[image]

Is there a way to do it in python or other languages?

Answer (score 1):

First let me tell you that this is not an easy problem to solve since PDF files in the wild tend to be quite diverse in layouts. I can suggest trying an open source project that works really good for extracting information from tables in PDF files. It is called Tabula, you can get it at https://tabula.technology.

Tabula is going to detect tables on each page and export the content as CSV format. Once you have it in CSV it should be easier to get the information using Python. Please note that the CSV layout depends on the table layout in the PDF, meaning that you may need to create several functions to extract the information correctly.

Tabula is not perfect but it should work with most PDF files, for those that do not work you may need to extract the information manually.